# how i can add an object to a nested array in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
const initState = {
    questions:[
    {
      id: uuidv4(), 
      answers:[
        {answerid: uuidv4()},
        {answerid: uuidv4()}
      ]
    },
    ],
}
```

this is the state i wanna function to add object in the answers array so the state will be after add like that:

```
const initState = {
    questions:[
    {
      id: uuidv4(), 
      answers:[
        {answerid: uuidv4()},
        {answerid: uuidv4()},
        {answerid: uuidv4()}
      ]
    },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a library like [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/update-patterns#nested-data-structures) for deeply nested objects update,

My try as below

```js
const initState = {
  questions: [
    {
      id: 1,
      answers: [
        {
          answerid: 34,
        },
        {
          answerid: 12,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const newState = {
  ...initState,
  questions: initState.questions.map((q) => {
    const newq = {
      ...q,
      answers: [
        ...q.answers,
        {
          a: "b",
        },
      ],
    };
    return newq;
  }),
};

newState.questions[0].id = 2;   // to test it doesn't mutate original object

console.log({initState, newState});
```

Comment: ok bro but when i add answer the answer added to all questions, i want to add answer only for the question i want.

Comment: check the question with an if condition and then run the same code